Troubleshooting Auto-Formatting Issues with Lambda Expressions in Visual Studio 2022
Why isn't auto-formatting working for this lambda expression in Visual Studio 2022? Here’s the code snippet.
if (Main.main.player.SaveData.XPLevel >= 6)
{
    //Wonderful! Now that we've reached Level 6, we can upgrade our farm buildings and unlock new types of feed for our adorable animals. Let’s make our farm even more thriving and vibrant!
    if (CheckDialog(new[]
    {
        new farmDialogInfo("dialogs/dialog33",DialogCharacter.Hope,
        null,()=>
        {
             Main.main.player.SaveData.FarmDialogs.Add("dialogs/dialog33");

                             Farm.instance.FarmGrid.SelectedFarmItem?.DeSelect();
                            Farm.instance.CameraZoom.VoltaParaoZoomPadrao();
                            Farm.instance.CameraZoom.PointCameraToObjectBottomScreen = Farm.instance.FarmTutorial.FarmFeedMill.gameObject;
                            ShowHelpMask1(new Vector2(500,500), Farm.instance.FarmCameraToUICamera(Farm.instance.FarmTutorial.FarmHouse.transform.position.Translate(-100,485,0)),Farm.instance.FarmTutorial.FarmHouse.gameObject,150,450);


                            ArrowFarmHouse.transform.SetParent(Farm.instance.FarmTutorial.FarmHouse.transform);
                            ArrowFarmHouse.ShowLocalPosition(new Vector3(0, 800, 0), 1f, ArrowType.LocalPosition);
                            Farm.instance.CameraZoom.PointCameraToObject=Farm.instance.FarmTutorial.FarmHouse.gameObject;

               CheckDialog(new[]                {                    new farmDialogInfo("dialogs/dialog33",DialogCharacter.FaceHope)                });                })

}))
        yield break;

}

What can I do to fix the formatting issue?

which line do you want to achieve the auto-formatting function? Could you provide a  Minimal, Reproducible Example so that I can know your question more clearly？

do you have any update for the question?

All content following Main.main.player.SaveData.FarmDialogs.Add("dialogs/dialog33"); should be aligned to the left.
The spacing on
CheckDialog(new[]                {                    new farmDialogInfo("dialogs/dialog33",DialogCharacter.FaceHope)                });                })
should be removed.
The same code outside ()=> { } formats as expected.

Based on my test, I reproduced the same problem with you. When C# code is placed in Lambda expression, Ctrl K + Ctrl F cannot format the C# code automatically.
I recommend that you could report the problem in Developer Community.

I discovered it on the Developer Community. This bug has been reported since 2018.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/31416

@Cezar Wagenheimer, thanks for the feedback! To help ensure this issue gets more visibility, it might be worth either continuing the discussion here on GitHub or reporting it on the Microsoft Developer Community. Issues with more upvotes on the Developer Community tend to attract greater attention from the dev team, which might help expedite a resolution.
