Why do some syntaxes in Visual Studio get the wrong indentation?
Screenshot illustrating problem:

Code:
                // Extract task details from the JSON output
                var tasks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Task>>(jsonOutput);

                // Filter tasks with empty items
                var emptyTasks = tasks.Where(task => task.Items.Length == 0)
.Select(task => new TaskWithArea(task, area.Name))
.ToList();

                // Create the Graphviz graph and save as SVG
                CreateGraph(tasks, $"{area.Name}.svg");

Here the .Select and .ToList get indented to the left
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - current
version 17.11.5

Format document won't indent these lines, but indentation after pressing enter is correct, my version 17.12.2.

And your VS formatting settings and potential editorconfig settings are?

Are you editing as a file outside or within a project open?

@DanielA.White No. all inside VS

you mean in your version .Select() is indent just below var emtpyTasks ?  @shingo I should have the default. hasnt change  anything there

What settings should I look for? @Ralf

Don't know. I think there is no single setting that that will lead to this behavior but certain combination might. I would start looking if there is a .editorconfig file in the path to this file/project and inspect that. Something in there is likely more unexpected to you then the standard visual studio code formatting settings.

Yes, I uploaded an image to show what happened: https://www.imghippo.com/i/lhdQ1868pHA.gif

Take a look at Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> C# -> Code style -> Formatting -> Indentation. Maybe you can change it there..

This is related to lambda expressions. Here is a similar post you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79040821/troubleshooting-auto-formatting-issues-with-lambda-expressions-in-visual-studio
